# EntityFrameWork Update Multiple Rows

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

For example I have table like this

Table
ID -- CategotyID -- ProductName 
 1 --------- 4 ----------Coca-Cola 
 2 --------- 7 ----------Tea 
 3 --------- 4 ----------Sprite

When I write in entityframework this code: 
 `var list= db.Table.Where(w => w.CategotyID == 4).ToList();`
`list.ForEach(update => update.ProductName = "Fanta");`
`db.SaveChanges()`
 I saw in SQL Profiler executes this statement separately like this
`update Table set ProductName = "Fanta" where ID = 1`
`update Table set ProductName = "Fanta" where ID = 3`

How can I write from SQL to EntityFrameWork this statement?
`update Table set ProductName = "Fanta" where CategoryID = 4` 
 Don't wont to SQL Server executes it separately

Comment: Entity Framework doesn't support this, but luckily, as the answers to that other question show, the main work to allow it anyway has already been done by others.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think you can't do with. Entity Framework is doing this under the hood.

Maybe you can try it with LINGQ to SQL.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26657/Simple-LINQ-to-SQL-in-C